# Can't set state inside a method that gets called in render

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I know there are a bunch of answers out there for this question, but I feel like none of them were quite what I was looking for.  My problem is that I have this application that gets a list of stores within a desired radius.  When I click submit, I populate an array with those stores information.  What I want to do is be able to store some of that information into an array in my react state.  My main issue is that I would like to set state when that information is populated, but this causes an infinite loop because setState calls the render method again.  Hopefully this explains my issue a little better, there is some code to go with this below as well.  Any help is appreciated, thanks!

stores.js

```
Class stores extends React.Component{
 constructor(props){
  this.state = {
   StoreInfo: [],
   Zip: "",
   Radius: ""
  }
}

RenderTable(zip, radius){

.... some stuff to generate stores within this location

storeInfo = []

for(var i = 0; i < storeArray.length; i++){
  storeInfo.push(storeArray.info);
}

this.setState({StoreInfo: storeInfo});


... generate html to be rendered


}


render(){

var renderPage = (

<div>
 {this.RenderTable(this.state.Zip, this.state.Radius)}
</div>

);

return renderPage;

}
```

This is obviously just an example of what my code does, and is not the exact file since the original is thousands of lines long.

Comment: I dont really get your question. If you update your state on click that should only re-render once. why is it rendering non stop. Do you change your on every render?

Comment: What's your question? You can't call `setState` inside the render method, but you already seem to be aware of that, so what do you want to know?

Comment: @Michael, why is your code thousands of line? You should consider classifying your code into sub components and js files.

Comment: @Aye_baybae it isn't my code to begin with.  Just came into this job, and this is the code that I'm given.  I agree that some things need to be changed, but I'm trying to work with what I've got atm.

Comment: @Herohtar I want to know how I can get the info from within the RenderTable method into my react state so that I can use it elsewhere in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do it on render(). Instead, you can do it using the hook componentDidMount() inside your class, like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
if(this.state.StoreInfo.length === 0) {
//set your state here
}
}
```

Inside your if statement, you can verify the length of some data to prevent it to enter in the render loop, don't need to be the length of some information array inside your state, but something that flags to your code that you already loaded up the information. You can also create a bool for this and set it to true (or false) when you load your data.